# Representing non-contiguous memoryviews with Cython

Tags: cython

Quick example to see right away what I am talking about:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10*30, dtype=np.float64).reshape(10, 30)

arr_slice = arr[::2]
arr_tile = arr[:3, :5]
```

Provided a `shape`, `strides` and a `double*` pointer, how can I represent `arr_slice` or `arr_tile` as memoryviews in cython?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation about typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html)? You shouldn't need a shape, strides, or a double pointer...

Comment: Of course I've read that. If you don't like the question, then let's rephrase it: look at `arr_tile`. I want to cast it to a `double[:, :, :]` and keep the same strides. I wrote `double[:, :, :]`, *not* `double[:, :]`. No copy allowed.

Comment: That actually confuses me a lot more. `arr_tile` is a 2D array so I really don't know how you'd assign it to a 3D memoryview. With respect to "no copy allowed" - a memoryview never makes a copy.

Comment: `arr_3D = arr_tile[:, :, None]` does it just fine. **C** is why: the C lib I'm wrapping assumes 3D and lesser dimensions are special cases of 3D. I know I don't technically need to get such representation in Cython, just like `numpy` is a completely useless lib since we have `bytes` in python and one can do "arrays" just fine with raw bytes... But at some point, easier is just easier. Regarding "no copy": cool, how do I make a memoryview of `arr_tile` that behaves just like `arr_tile[:, :, None]`?

Comment: As for why `arr_3D = arr_tile[:, :, None]` in python is not OK: I need to accept any buffer object (like `bytes` typically) to recast. In those cases, everything is contiguous and work well. Non-contiguous arrays are the last problem I have. I don't want to depend on numpy either to cast from that: none of my code depends on numpy and I don't see why it would. Yet numpy supports the buffer protocol and non-contiguous arrays are supported by the C code I wrap.

Comment: Right - now I understand the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I still think I might have missed the point of the question, but: if you can reshape/slide it with Numpy then you can assign it to a Cython typed memoryview with the appropriate number of dimensions:

```
cdef double[:,:] arr_tile_2d = arr[:3, :5]
cdef double[:,:,:] arr_tile_3d = arr[:3, :5, None]
```

These are all views of the data rather than copies of the data so changing them will change the underlying Numpy array.

---

In terms of the comment

> As for why `arr_3D = arr_tile[:, :, None]` in python is not OK: I need to accept any buffer object (like bytes typically) to recast. In those cases, everything is contiguous and work well. Non-contiguous arrays are the last problem I have. I don't want to depend on numpy either to cast from that: ...

From [the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#newaxis): if `arr_tile` is a typed memoryview then you can add the extra axes using the Numpy-like syntax with no dependency on Numpy.

So you'd assign your bytes/bytearray object to a 1d memoryview and then use `mview_1d[None, :, None]` to make it 3d.

Another option to change the shape/type of an object is to go via a [*Python* `memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) and the `cast` method. This can be used to change how you view any object that has the buffer protocol. You can then assign it to a Cython memoryview for quick access to the data.